# C++ List pop and push data race

Tags: c++, multithreading, std

For std::list  l, 
In thread1,  I did 
    l.push_back
In thread2,  I did 
    while (l.size() > 1) l.pop_front()
When these two threads running concurrently, I got data races.

What confuses me is,  I've checked if l.size is bigger than one before I pop_front, 
So, when push_back, there's no case the object pushed back will have a Null predecessor,
then I can't get it why there's data race in this.

Below is the code In my test:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

HANDLE gsem = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 2, 2, NULL);
unsigned long __stdcall threadPoc(list<int>* l);
unsigned long __stdcall threadPoc2(list<int>* l);
int main()
{
  std::list<int> l;
  unsigned long a1, a2;
  HANDLE t[2];
  t[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadPoc, &l, 0, &a1);
  t[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadPoc2, &l, 0, &a2);

  ReleaseSemaphore(gsem, 2, NULL);

  WaitForMultipleObjects(2, t, TRUE, INFINITE);

  return 0;
}
bool exf = false;
unsigned long __stdcall threadPoc(list<int>* l)
{
  WaitForSingleObject(gsem, INFINITE);
  for (int i=0; i<100000; i++)
    l->push_back(i);
  exf = true;
  return 0;
}

unsigned long __stdcall threadPoc2(list<int>* l)
{
  WaitForSingleObject(gsem, INFINITE);
  while (l->size()>1 || !exf)
    l->pop_front();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to use a mutex to prevent this problem

Comment: Think about this: What would happen if there is only one node in the list, and thread 2 is in the middle of it's `pop_front` when it's preempted and thread 1 starts (or even finishes) with a `push_back`. Chaos is likely to ensue.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I think this while (l->size()>1 || !exf) has excluded the case when there's only one node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrency is a big topic, firstly I refer you to read through "C++ Concurrency in Action" by Anthony Williams, you will understand almost everything after reading this book.

First of all, remember one thing, there is always a conflict when one thread is write, and another thread is read/write to the same object.

Secondly, for your specific question, there are apparently several places of conflict.

1. l.push_back will most probably (well, depends on the list implementation) change the size, l.size() is a read, so it's a write-read conflict on the same variable size. And l.pop_front will most probably change the size too, so it is a write-write conflict. Consider when both push_back & pop_front change size, the size will corrupt.
2. It seems that l.push_back & l.pop_front got no write-write conflict because C++'s list is a doubly linked list, and push_back/pop_front are not dealing with the same variable, but you might be wrong. One apparent thing is, push_back() might involve memory allocation, pop_front() might involve memory deallocation. The memory stuff is dealt by the template-id Alloc. You have a very good chance that the memory allocation/deallocation have conflict. It all depends on the  implementation, where different libraries may have different implementation.

Answer (score 0):

When adding an element to the back of a list, you typically need to do the following:

1. take the last element of the list
2. let the last element in the list point to the new element
3. let the new element point backwards to the last element
4. let the list point to the new last element

If your list contains 1 element, and another thread removes the element in between steps 1 and 2, your list will be corrupt.

Either protect your list using a mutex (CriticalSection), or use a lock-free list (e.g. concurrent_queue from Microsoft's PPL library, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504906.aspx#queue).

Comment: but when there's only one element, I didn't do pop, while (l->size()>1 || !exf),, so I guess it's not the case you mentioned

Comment: You don't know.  It depends on the implementation.  The implementation might also increment the count first before updating its internal pointers.  So in that case you may need to check for >2 instead of >1.